# BLE Pairing confirmation dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an android app which connects with BLE device .When I try to connect using `device.createBond()` some time following dialog appeared on the app. 
[image]

Can anybody please tell me why this dialog is appearing as it is not 100% reproducible it is showing very rarely. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you make custom dialog and get pairing key input and then pair pro-grammatically?

Comment: @SalmanNaseem, 
I am pairing pro-grammatically right now, but this pop up is shown by android OS sometimes. And even I cant have steps to reproduce that everytime. I want to know why this is appearing.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378224/7507520) out to bypass the popup.

Comment: @SalmanNaseem this popup is not appearing every time it is appearing very rarely. can you please tell me how to test after add priority ?

Comment: Os initiate pairing process when you call `bluetoothGatt.creatBound()` method.

Comment: Thanks for helping @SalmanNaseem